# No output in VS Code when running tests

Tags: c#, .net-core, visual-studio-code

I'm running an *XUnit* test-ptoject in VS Code with the *.NET Core Test Explorer* extension. I'm trying to write output during the tests but nothing is working. I've tried writing output in different ways, but can't see any output anywhere. Has anyone managed to see output in vs code somehow while running tests?

Here is a small example class:

```
using Xunit;
using Xunit.Abstractions;
using System.Diagnostics;

public class TestClass
{

    private ITestOutputHelper _output;


    public TestClass(ITestOutputHelper output)
    {
        _output = output;
    }

    [Fact]
    public void Test2()
    {
        _output.WriteLine("Hello");
        Debug.WriteLine("Hello");
        Console.WriteLine("Hello");
    }
}
```

Comment: Other way around: why do you want logging? Your tests should be small and fail fast using asserts. If they fail you use the debugger to analyze?

Comment: System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Hello") should work, if you out a breakpoint and by console.writeline do you see it in the output?

Comment: I'm not debugging the tests, I'm just running them. In Visual Studio I'm able to see test output when just running the tests, the reason is that it's a lot quicker to run a test than to debug it (much more loading time). When running a test over and over it saves a lot of time. Running a test is also a lot quicker than restarting the whole application all the time. What I'm looking for is a way to run and alter a code snippet as efficiently as possible.

Answer (score 6):

Output only shows if the test fails.

If you need to to see your output, you can (temporarily) add this line at the end of the test:

```
Assert.False(true, "Fail on purpose");
```

If you're running in VS Code, the test output will be visible in the "OUTPUT" tab when you set the source to "Test Explorer (Test runner output)" in the drop-down on the right.

Comment: Thank you for mentioning where to find the output in VSCode. It's in a really non-obvious place. Note to future readers -- as of early 2024 with the latest standard C# extensions from Microsoft, the source to select in the dropdown of the OUTPUT tab is called "C# Dev Kit - Test Explorer".