# How to show Console.WriteLine's message in VsCode Testing in C#

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-code, testing, mstest

I have a `MSTest` project in my solution like this:

```cs
[TestClass]
public class Tests{

   [TestMethod]
   public void Test1(){

      var result = "Hello 1";
      Console.WriteLine(result);

   }
}
```

In VsCode's `Testing` window `Hello 1` is not showing in Test Results generally; But when use `Assert.Fail(result)`, its works!

How to capture `Console.WriteLine` in Test Results without `exception` or `Assert.Fail` ?

I Try bellow codes but not works!

```cs
Console.WriteLine()
Logger.LogMessage()
ConsoleOutput.Instance.Error()
Debug.WriteLine()
Trace.WriteLine()
```

Comment: Answered here [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64317627/no-output-in-vs-code-when-running-tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64317627/no-output-in-vs-code-when-running-tests)

Answer (score 1):

you can use TestContext like this

```
[TestClass]
public class Tests
{
    private TestContext _testContextInstance;

    public TestContext TestContext
    {
        get { return _testContextInstance; }
        set { _testContextInstance = value; }
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void Test1()
    {
        var result = "Hello 1";
        _testContextInstance.WriteLine(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, but not woked!